# Google Cloud Platform: reserved address disassociated without reason

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Today (15/06/2018) we found two reserved addresses were disassociated from two GCE instances.
Nobody ordered this disassociation, in fact in the activity logs we do not found any activity on this two reserved addresses.

We manually re-associate the two reserved addresses to our machines to solve the problem.

Is it possible to know what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Good sources to see what happened are the "Activity" tab in the Cloud Console as well as the AuditLog entries in Stackdriver Logging. If it is still not clear what happened based on that, please file a support case for further investigation.

Comment: The "Activity" tab in the Cloud Console does not show any activity bind to GCE Reserved Address. It only shows our activities related to our operations to re-associate the two reserved address to our machines (this obviously solve the problem). So we are not able to identify the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your instances were in the stopped state at the time it may be related to this incident:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/18005

Answer (score 0):

By reading this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) I ran the following advanced filter from Stackdriver:

> resource.type="gce_instance"
>   jsonPayload.event_subtype="compute.instances.deleteAccessConfig"

This filter shows the actor (user or a service account) and the event type (how it happened).

If you need further information, I would suggest filling an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).